# Flink KDA truststore location not working

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using AWS(Kinesis Data analytics) to deploy flink service to consume data using KafkaSource, while passing the ssl.truststore.location, receiving below
"Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore truststore.jks of type JKS" , any suggestion/guidance on this much appreciated?

1. I tried getClassLoader().getResource("truststore.jks").getPath() did not worked
2. changed the directory moved from resources to main also
3. Tried to read from S3 bucket also to convert into bytes format.